# How to get the shortcut menu name of Intent?

Tags: android

I can use the following code to get the  packageName and the activityInfo.name of a Intent.
But I hope to get a shortcut menu name such as "Add to dropbox" like the image below, how can I do ? Thanks!

[image]

```
private void GetShare() {
    Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
        for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase()
                    +" CW "                     
                    +info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase()
                    ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it with `activityInfo.labelRes`

Edit:
That only returns an int referencing the String res ID. You still have to get that package's res to map it to the correct String.

Comment: PackageManager pm = getPackageManager(); pm.getApplicationLabel(r.activityInfo.applicationInfo);